# Find a solution of large system of inequalities

Tags: optimization, python, c++, linear-programming

I have a large system of homogenous inequalities involving 33 real unknowns of the form

$$
\vec{F}(z_i)^T \cdot \vec{X}>0\,
$$

where $\vec{X} = \left(x_1,...,x_{24}\right)^T$ are the unknowns and $\vec{F}(z_i)$ are functions depending on a real parameter $|z_i|<1$ which parametrises the system, that is to each value of $z_i$ is associated an inequality. An example might be $\vec{F}(z) = \left(z^2+z\,,\, z^3+1/z,...,0.1 z^4 + 1/\sqrt{z}\right)^T $ but I am interested into more general cases.

I am interested in finding a point $\vec{X}_0$ which satisfy the system of inequalities resulting from the very big set of parameters $\{z_i\}$. Let say, we select 100 different parameters $z_i$, then we have 100 inequalities to solve.

I have tried to solve this problem with `Mathematica`, which has a function `FindInstance` which does this job. This function works very well for smaller systems, whereas it fails for large system of inequalities.

**Questions**

- Is there a way to study this problem by using Python or C++?
- Are there already dedicated libraries to solve such kind of problems?
- I want to find a set of points $\{\vec{X}\}$ which solves the system.

Comment: Your problem seems to be finding a feasible point for a set of inequality constraints.

Comment: @nicoguaro actually it is a feasible test problem. I am not an expert of this, and I am reading something about linear programming around in the internet. Any suggestion, is welcome!

Comment: Have you checked [SciPy.optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html#scipy.optimize.linprog)?

Comment: Are you really interested in the intersection of *open* half spaces? That's numerically not useful.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth yes, I am really interested in the strictly positive inequality. Do you mean that's hard to solve this problem numerically? I understand the difficulties...

Comment: It doesn't make any sense numerically. From a practical perspective, 0 and 1e-16 are the same if you are operating with floating point numbers on the order of 1.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I understand your answer. However, as the system of inequalities is huge (actually, it's infinite dimensional as I can choose infinite different values of $z$) I may expect to find two or more inequalities (or a positive linear combination of them) that lead to a contradiction. The task is to do it numerically. If you want, you can enlarge the inequality by considering $\vec{F}\cdot \vec{X} \geq 0$ where the equality holds if and only if $\vec{X} = 0$. The zero vector may be the only allowed point.

Comment: Where I'm getting at is that the usual non-emptiness (feasibility) test of linear constraints tries to find a vertex of the polyhedron described by the constraints. This is usually done by using the dual formulation of the associated linear problem -- every book on linear optimization will have a chapter on that. But if you have an open set as you do here, all vertices are in fact infeasible.

Comment: Solving the strict inequality $Ax > 0$ is the same as solving the nonstrict inequality $Ax \ge \mathbf{1}$ where $\mathbf{1}$ is the vector of ones. You can apply a standard off-the-shelf solver for the latter.

Answer (score 3):

The goal is to compute an $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to satisfy the strict
inequalities
$$
f(z_{i})^{T}x>0\qquad\forall z_{i}\in\{1,\ldots,m\}.\tag{1}
$$
If we write $\epsilon>0$ as the smallest margin of feasibility, that
is
$$
\epsilon=\min_{i}\{f(z_{i})^{T}x\},
$$
then (1) is equivalent to 
$$
f(z_{i})^{T}x\ge\epsilon>0\qquad\forall z_{i}\in\{1,\ldots,m\}.\tag{2}
$$
**Proposition.** There exists a pair $(x,\epsilon)$ satisfying
the strict inequality (2) if and only if there exists $y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$
satisfying the nonstrict inequality (3) below
$$
f(z_{i})^{T}y\ge1\qquad\forall z_{i}\in\{1,\ldots,m\}.\tag{3}
$$

*Proof.* **If.** Any $y$ satisfying (3) also yields the
pair $(y,1)$ satisfying (2). **Only if.** By contradiction,
suppose that there exists no $y$ satisfying (3) but there exists
a pair $(x,\epsilon)$ satsifying (2). Then $y=x/\epsilon$ satisfies
(3)--- a contradiction.

Hence, we can just go and find a choice of $y$ satisfying (3). Any
standard off-the-shelf linear programming solver will solve
(3) in standard canonical form
$$
\begin{gather*}
\min_{z}\quad c^{T}z\quad\text{subject to }\quad Az=b,\quad z\ge0,\\
\max_{y}\quad b^{T}y\quad\text{subject to }\quad A^{T}y\le c,
\end{gather*}
$$
with data
$$
A=-\begin{bmatrix}f(z_{1}) & \cdots & f(z_{m})\end{bmatrix}^T,\qquad b=0,\qquad c=-\begin{bmatrix}1 & \cdots & 1\end{bmatrix}^T.
$$
A problem with $n\approx m\approx100$ is extremely small.
In this case, you can also try 3 lines of MATLAB code using
ADMM. (See the [Boyd et al. survey](http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/admm.html) for more details. At the risk of a little self-promotion, the specific derivations can be found in Section IV-C of our [tutorial paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.08841.pdf)):
$$
\begin{align*}
y^{k+1} & =(AA^{T})^{-1}A\left[c-s^{k}-z^{k}/t\right]\\
s^{k+1} & =\max\{0,c-A^{T}y^{k+1}-z^{k}/t\}\\
z^{k+1} & =z^{k}+t(A^{T}y^{k+1}+s^{k+1}-c)
\end{align*}
$$
Here, you can pick any step-size $t>0$ and just set the initial points
to zero. [See also Jacob Mattingley's page on ridiculously short LP solvers.](https://jemnz.com/lp75.html)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I will try to learn how to use linear programming solvers and will come back to you

Comment: I should note that if a choice of $x$ does not exist, then you can use Lagrange duality to certify it. The geometrical interpretation is to generate a separating hyperplane that has the space $\mathrm{span}(A)$ on one side and the cone $x>0$ on the other. Such a plane is indeed naturally computed by any LP solver

Answer (score 2):

Here are two considerations that might help you figure out whether a solution exists:

- First, if there is a vector $X$ so that $F(z_i) \cdot X > 0$, then all vectors $Y=\alpha X$ for any choice of $\alpha>0$ are also solutions because $F(z_i) \cdot Y = \alpha \underbrace{(F(z_i)\cdot X)}_{\ge 0} > 0$. In other words, if a solution exists, then there are in fact infinitely many solutions.
- Second, let's forget that the $F(z_i)$ vectors are really some kind of parameterized version. They are really just a bunch of vectors $F_i$ that happen to be created in a special way. Then the inequality $F_i \cdot X>0$ really just means that $X$ must lie in the (open) half space cut out of all of ${\mathbb R}^n$ by the plane that is perpendicular to the vector $F_i$. A vector $X$ that satisfies *all* of the inequalities $F_i \cdot X>0, i=1,\ldots,n$ must therefore lie in the *intersection* of the $n$ half spaces. The question of existence of a solution then boils down to the question whether the intersection of the $n$ half spaces is non-empty. This is a geometric question. For example, if you were in 2d, then if you had vectors $F_1=(1,0), F_2=(-1,0)$ then the (open) half-spaces are mutually exclusive and so no solution exists. The same would be true if you had $F_1=(1,0), F_2=(-1,1), F_3=(-1,-1)$, even though the intersection of each pair of half spaces is non-empty.

Out of this second consideration, I suspect that you can build an algorithm that determines whether the intersection of the first $k$ half spaces with the $(k+1)$st half space is non-empty. I'd have to think about this in more depth to come up with an algorithm, but maybe you can do a literature search about the intersection of half spaces to come up with something useful. The point worth mentioning is that the intersection of your half spaces is a cone rooted at the origin that I suspect can be described by the intersection of the dividing planes of each half space; these are low dimensional objects easily amenable to to linear algebra.

Of course, there is also the possibility to use the special structure of the $F_i$ to prove that a solution does or does not exist. For example, if you can show that there is a direction $Y$ so that all of the $F_i=F(z_i)$ have an angle less than 90 degree from $Y$ (i.e., $Y\cdot F_i>0$), then it is geometrically clear that $Y$ is a vector that satisfies the desired inequalities. Of course, you may not know $Y$, but maybe the statement is true for $Y=F(z_1)$, for example.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have already thought the geometrical interpretation of the problem, which of course coincides with yours. For instance, I have tried to construct the convex-hull generated by the different points $\vec{F}_i$ and see whether or not $\vec{0}$ belongs to the convex-hull. This might be a proof that the system in impossible. However, constructing high-dimensional convex hulls is challenging and it seems to me that $\vec{0}$ belongs likely to the boundary of the convex-hull. So, since $0$ is the same as $10^{-30}$, this method might not be appropriate.

Comment: I think the convex hull is not a useful tool here. That's because you can scale these $F_i$ arbitrarily: If you replace once constraint $F_i \cdot X>0$ by $(2F_i)\cdot X>0$, nothing actually changes. So you need to find a representation of your problem that takes this into account. The representation as a cone I mentioned is something that respects this invariance.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\vec{F}(z_i)$ is a constant once the parameter $z_i$ has been chosen, the problem amounts to solving a system $\mathbf{A}\vec x>0$ for which $\vec x =0$ is trivially a feasible point.

**EDIT**

The problem is that no optimization software implements strict inequalities. One reason for this is that the difference between say, 1e-999 and 0 is really, really small. So, operationally, a strict equality and an equality shakeout to the same answer. Let's explore this a bit.

[cvxpy](https://www.cvxpy.org/) is a Python package that allows you to write a linear program in a generic way and then pass it to one of a large number solvers. Like most such programs, it does not allow for strict inequalities.

I've written a representation of your problem below:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np 

def f(z):
  return np.array([
    z**2+z-3,
    z**3+1/z,
    0.1*z**4+1/np.sqrt(z),
    -4
  ])

#Generate 100 random numbers in [-1,1)
zs = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=100)
#Run the function on each number
zs = [f(z) for z in zs]
#Strip out results with a NaN
zs = [z for z in zs if not any(np.isnan(z))]

zs = [[-1,-1,-1,-1],[1,1,1,1]]

#x vector of length four to match length of vector from `f`
x = cp.Variable(4)

#Multiply f(z)'s by x's and build constraints
cons = [z*x>=0 for z in zs]

#Constant objective implies a problem in which we only want to find a feasible
#point
obj = cp.Maximize(1) 

#Create a problem with the objective and constraints
prob = cp.Problem(obj, cons)

#Solve problem, get optimal value
val = prob.solve()

if val==-np.inf:
  print("NO SOLUTION FOUND")
else:
  print(x.value)
```

If we run the above code, we find that the solver indeed finds the 0-vector as an answer.

Now, you would like your answer to be strictly greater than zero. Since there is no solver that will do this (that I know of), one way to achieve it is to ask the solver to find a solution to a different problem. Rather than solving $Ax>0$, we can ask the solver to find $Ax\ge\epsilon$. Where $\epsilon$ is some small value. Since all you want is a feasible point, this is a reasonable approach since any solution to $Ax\ge\epsilon$ is also a solution to $Ax>0$. This is the simple solution you thought you were looking for.

We can implement this by changing the line:

```
cons = [z*x>=0 for z in zs]
```

to

```
cons = [z*x>=0.0001 for z in zs]
```

Running the code again, I get the answer:

```
[ 1.34351053e-09 -9.62045447e-10  5.11738862e-09 -3.99990907e-05]
```

(You may get a different answer because the solvers leverage stochasticity.) This looks promising! But there's a caveat here... What if we use this program?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np 

#A system with no solution
zs = [[-1,-1,-1,-1],[1,1,1,1]]

#x vector of length four to match length of vector from `f`
x = cp.Variable(4)

#Multiply f(z)'s by x's and build constraints
cons = [z*x>=0.0001 for z in zs]

#Constant objective implies a problem in which we only want to find a feasible
#point
obj = cp.Maximize(1) 

#Create a problem with the objective and constraints
prob = cp.Problem(obj, cons)

#Solve problem, get optimal value
val = prob.solve()

if val==-np.inf:
  print("NO SOLUTION FOUND")
else:
  print(x.value)
```

It's obvious from inspection that there can be no solution satisfying this system. Interestingly, however, when you run the program (using the default solver) the 0-vector is returned as an answer! If we modify the program to read:

```
cons = [z*x>=0.001 for z in zs]
```

the same thing happens. Only when we get to:

```
cons = [z*x>=0.01 for z in zs]
```

do we finally get the correct response: that there is no solution.

There are a few reasons for this:

- Internally, the solver is using a floating-point representation whose limited precision results in it *thinking* it's solved the problem when it really hasn't. (You could deal with this by using a rational-number solver that does its calculations using fractional representations.)
- More generally, the solver may not be numerically robust. The subfield of "robust optimization" can be leveraged to find disciplined ways of handling this.
- Philosophically, asking the solver to differentiate between small values of epsilon and 0 is silly. Say you're optimizing the floor plan of a house using numbers which represent metres and choose epsilon as 1e-10. You're asking for a solution that differs from zero by the width of an atom. Say you're calculating a solar trajectory with numbers representing astronomical units (1 AU is the distance from Earth to the sun - 93 million miles): the difference between 1e-10 and 0 is 50 feet (the width of a house).

Perhaps the simplest way of dealing with the problems above is to rescale your system so that small values *are* unimportant. For instance, rather than measuring my floorplan in meters, I could measure it in millimeters.

It's worth noting that there is an entire class of problems for which your question has trivial and reliable solutions. If any column of your $A$ matrix contains only positive values greater than zero, then setting that column's corresponding $x$ value to 1 and all other $x$ values to 0 provides an answer. Similarly, if any column contains only negative values then choosing -1 for the corresponding $x$ value and 0 elsewhere provides an answer.

Comment: Why $\vec{x}=0$?

Comment: Because if you multiply any $\vec F(z_i)$ by $\vec 0$, you get 0, which satisfies your constraint (since you use a strict inequality, in practice you perturb $\vec 0$ by an infinitesimal positive amount).

Comment: I don't get this answer. The inequality is strict: $Ax>0$. $x=0$ does not satisfy the inequality.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: Edited.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense. For example, assume $x\in\mathbb R$ and that $A$ is just the matrix with entries $[1 ; -1]$, corresponding to the inequalities $x>0$ and $x<0$. The problem has no feasible point. It also does not have a feasible point if you replace the zero by epsilon: $x>\varepsilon$ and $-x>\varepsilon$ still has no solution. But the problem with $\ge 0$ *does* have a feasible point, namely $x=0$.

Comment: @Wolfgang: I'm sorry if I've been confusing; I'm not sure what else to do. This shows how you can approach solving your problem via Python, points out numerical pitfalls, and suggests an algorithm for special cases. At some point you'll need to contend with solvers' preferences for weak inequalities, though.

Comment: +1 for "differs from zero by the width of an atom" (even worse in 3d, volume of an atom, let alone 10d)